# Gulp error when minimize js

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, bower, minimize

I decide to ask because I have been 2 days trying to solve this problem. Im a little bit *n00b* with this task runner.

I'm using Gulp with [**Slush**](http://slushjs.github.io/#/) using this generator:
[**https://www.npmjs.com/package/slush-webapp**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slush-webapp)

When I run ´gulp serve´ all goes OK and I dont have problems.

But when I run ´gulp´, in the javascript minimice process, I get this error:
[**http://pastebin.com/4mPq2jEU**](http://pastebin.com/4mPq2jEU)

As I know, CSS is working and it's minimized. Images are working fine too.

When I open the chrome's console  I see an error log,saying something about "undefined function"

Tried to solve add in the beggining of the .js files (jquery plugins) the sentence

```
'use strict';
```

trying to use closures too or something, but is not working.

Any help? Thx,

Jorge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put in some third-party libraries in your app folder which don't comply to the JSHint rules. That's why you get that fat error stack. Things you can do:

1. Open your Gulpfile, and remove the JSHint task from your build:

   ```
   gulp.task('build', ['lint', 'html', 'images', 'fonts', 'misc']);

   /* to */

   gulp.task('build', ['html', 'images', 'fonts', 'misc']);
   ```
2. exclude the third party scripts from your lint task:

   ```
   gulp.task('lint', function () {
       var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');

       return gulp.src(['app/scripts/**/*.js', '!app/script/path/to/script/that/fails.js'])
           .pipe(jshint())
           .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
   });
   ```
3. Put files which don't comply to the JSHint rules to another folder.

I guess that you most likely won't have your own files JSHint compliant, so I'd suggest 1. for a quick try, but read a little into dependency management and linting ;-)

Comment: Hello, thanks you. I have been reading about it, and realized that it's because 3rd part libraries, the file ".jshintrc". Im going to try your soultion. Thanks.

Comment: But i want to concat and minimize all the js files in 1 or 2 files (i have like 10 .js files), is that possible?

Comment: Running `gulp html` should actually do that judging from the Gulpfile of your generator

Comment: Hello, thanks. I already did the #1 solution (as **ddprrt** said) and it works fine, i have only 1 .js file. For now is OK.